# Как найти все файлы в Debian 7 c определенным текстом?

Tags: linux, bash

Помогите с консольной командой поиска всех файлов где встречается строка
"192.168.199.200"

> Debian 7

Comment: `grep -r '192\.168\.199\.200' /` наверное. Но вам стоит исключить точки монтирования, и вызвать команду на все интересующие точки монтирования по разу на точку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *grep*:

```
$ grep -rl регулярное-выражение /
```

- `-r` — рекурсивно
- `-l` — отображать только имена файлов
- `регулярное-выражение` — в вашем случае — `'192\.168\.199\.200'` (см. примечание)
- `/` — в корневом каталоге. но я подозреваю, что вам нужен всего лишь `/etc` или `/var`

---

ещё имеет смысл запускать команду от имени пользователя *root* — из его оболочки или с помощью, например, *sudo*:

```
$ sudo grep ...
```

---

и ещё имеет смысл убирать сообщения об ошибках, добавив `2>/dev/null` в конец команды

#### примечание

если добавить опцию `-F`, то метасимволы (в вашем случае — точки) можно не экранировать:

```
$ grep -rlF 192.168.199.200 /
```

Comment: @mymedia, да, имеет смысл об этом упомянуть. спасибо. дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Очень много задач решается связкой find+grep+xargs. Есть целый комплекс функций в Emacs работающий с ними.

Поиск всех файлов рекурсивно с избежанием ошибки "слишком много аргументов":

```
~$ find /path/to/dir -type f -print0
```

Если файлов больше миллиарда, разбиваем на потоки:

```
~$ find /path/to/dir -type f -print0 \
| xargs -P"$(nproc)" -0 grep "icq"
```

Если нужны имена файлов, где встречается "icq":

```
~$ find /path/to/dir -type f -exec grep -l "icq" {} \;
```

GNU findutils

https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html

GNU grep

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

GNU coreutilities

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#nproc-invocation

Ссылки

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-badunixhabits/index.html
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-find.html
- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix

Comment: Что такое 1ккк? Это один ку-клукс-клан? Зачем разбивать на потоки работу с файловой системой и дисками, ориентируясь на количество вычислительных процессоров?

Comment: 1k - 1000, 1kk - 1000000, 1kkk - 1000000000. Предположим у вас кеш сервер на SSD  где I/O очень высокое и 20ТБ файлов... http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=1kk